# two different app scoped user ids for one facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my database I have two different `app_scoped_user_id` for one facebook user.
How to compare two `app_scoped_user_id` and find dependency between them? 
Is there some unique information for one user?

Comment: there should only be one app scoped id per app. are you mixing two apps? if not, file a bug.

Comment: If this _is_ about using different apps, and being able to identify the user across them - Business Mapping API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: me?ids_for_business is giving me only one id.

Comment: What should i use to get app_scoped_user_id from this business api ?